# Handling questions about using device X on carrier Y

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

As some of you may have noticed, I recently posted a community wiki question/answer [Can I use my device on a different carrier?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/can-i-use-my-device-on-a-different-carrier)

My intent in doing this was to try to pare down the number of questions we get which all fit into this formula. We've done this in the past with recurring questions, and I think that this is a very good candidate for a canonical question/answer. Although the questions may be specific to a phone and carrier, the answers are always inevitably the same:

- Find the specs of the carrier (or available carriers, in the case of "Can I use X in country Y?")
- Find the specs of the phone
- Compare them to see if they run on the same networks and frequencies

In other words, I view this as a very ideal "teach a man to fish" situation, since we can readily point our users to sources which will provide the information they need rather than continuously looking up combinations of phones and carriers for them.

Ultimately, I would like to start closing questions as a duplicate of this one provided that it is well-received by the rest of the community. If you have any feedback or other thoughts - positive or negative - please use this question as a medium for your discussion.

Comment: Looks good to me! Good idea!